# Run python script in background while sending subprocess stdout and stderr to PIPE

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script (test.py) using subprocess to execute some bash commands and write bash commands stdout/stderr to a log file. It's working fine if running python in foreground like this:

```
python test.py -i 123 -d 567
```

However, if running test.py in background like this, subprocess seems doesn't send stdout/stderr to the log file any more.

```
python test.py -i 123 -d 567 > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Here is the code snippet about subprocess:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["xxx","xxx"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdoutdata, stderrdata = process.communicate()
log_output(stdoutdata, stderrdata)
```

where log_output() is a method using logging to write message to a file.

Please advise how to run python in background meanwhile send stdout/stderr to a log file.

Thanks!

Comment: I might be missing something, but it's a little hard to say without knowing what your "xxx" is doing.

Comment: You may be missing an error message by piping stderr and stdout (on the command-line) when you're trying to run it in the background.

Comment: The xxx is the beeline command used to execute hive sql. For example, Popen(["beeline", "-u", connection, "-f", hive_file], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE). It's working fine in foreground. Thanks in advance.